# Do an additional "WHERE" evaluation based on an "IF"

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos
WHERE YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
```

And I have this another one:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos
WHERE YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
AND DAY(eventos.date) = :day
```

**Question:
Is there any way to implement this logic?**

```
SELECT * FROM eventos
WHERE YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
AND IF(:day != NULL, WHERE DAY(eventos.date) = :day, '')
```

**So instead of 2 stored procedures that do almost the same, I have only this one.**

Comment: Do you really have two parameters `:day` and `:date`, or that's a typo?

Comment: yes, it was a typo, many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Based on all the answers**

Tried with "IS NULL", but it seems that, even when I don't pass the `day` parameter, it's an empty string value (`''`), nut a `NULL` value.

So, this:

```
AND (day = '' OR DAY(eventos.date) = day);
```

Worked.

I didn't see the MySQL logic at the start. Thank you all.

Comment: *I didn't see the MySQL logic* Why do you think MySQL is to blame? This is the fault of the software which prepares the query for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the second `WHERE`, just put the expression there.

Also, you can't compare with `NULL` using `=` or `!=`. You have to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`

```
AND IF(:day IS NOT NULL, DAY(eventos).date = :day, 1)
```

You can also use a logical expression:

```
AND (:day IS NULL OR DAY(eventos.date) = :day)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an `OR` here:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos
WHERE YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
AND (DAY(eventos.date) = :day OR :day IS NULL)
```

You can also use `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos
WHERE YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
AND COALESCE(:day, DAY(eventos.date)) = DAY(eventos.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventos
WHERE 
    YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
    AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
    AND (:day IS NULL OR DAY(eventos.date) = :day);
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM eventos
WHERE 
    YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
    AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
    AND DAY(eventos.date) = IFNULL(:day, DAY(eventos.date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine them:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos
WHERE YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
AND (:date IS NULL OR DAY(eventos.date) = :date)
```

Yours SP has other problem to worry about:
Since you are using functions (YEAR, MONTH or DAY)  on the date column, mysql will not be able to do index seek on the column if you have an index;

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do this with a `OR` condition:

```
SELECT * FROM eventos
WHERE 
    YEAR(eventos.date) = :year
    AND MONTH(eventos.date) = :month
    AND (:day is NULL OR DAY(eventos.date) = :day)
```

But I would futhermore suggest that you write this query differently. Splitting the date into parts with date functions like you do is inefficient, because it prevents the query to benefit an index on the date column. Instead, you want to do *explicit date comparison* with the *half-open strategy*.

Ideally, you should generate proper date parameters in your application (in format `yyyy-mm-dd`) and pass them to the query as follows:

```
WHERE eventos.date >= :start_date and eventos.date < :end_date
```

If that's not possible, then you can generate date boundaries on the fly using string concatenation and date arithemtics:

```
WHERE 
    eventos.date >= concat_ws('-', :year, :month, coalesce(:day, 1))
    and eventos.date < case 
        when :day is null then concat_ws('-', :year, :month, 1) + interval 1 month
        else concat_ws('-', :year, :month, :day) + interval 1 day
    end
```